# SQL Server connection string login failed

Tags: c#, connection-string, sql-server-express

I'm trying to access the SQL Server database I have on a server, I was originally using the string:

```
String MyConnection = @"Server=<Name>\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Accounts; Trusted_Connection = true;";
```

Which works, but only works if I'm logged into the domain. I want to try and access it from any computer which isn't on the domain. If the username, password of the domain is provided. I'm trying this:

```
String MyConnection = @"Server=<Name>\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Accounts; Integrated Security = false; User Id=" + na + "; Password=" + pa + ";";
```

I keep getting the error

> "login failed for user 'user'"

Any Suggestions how I can make it work?

Comment: Check if server allows Sql Server Authentication

Comment: It allows Server and windows athentication, When I was installing SQL I didn't make a SQL server authenticantion, I selected the Windows Authentication option

Comment: Loggin in from a computer not in a domain and trying to use the security information (Trusted_Connection) provided by the computer is nonsense. Instead when you pass user and password then you are using Sql Server Authentication. If I remember well, (just to try something) I was able to connect if the local user has the same name and password of a domain user and your local machine has some kind of domain resource already in use.

Comment: @Steve I'm using "integrated security = false" and then entering the username and password that are part of the domain. If I login the domain I would be using the same username as the variable "na" and same password as the variable "pa". I tried using "Integrated Security = SSPI" but  it's telling me the the login is from "untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication"

Comment: Again, if you specify User ID and Passwrd these values are from Sql Server Authentication list of valid user not the domain ones. See [ConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: have you actually granted that user (user id=user) access to the DB?

Comment: I don't think so, would I have to grant all the users in domain the access to DB one by one? if so, how?

Comment: There are only two security modes: 1. Windows + SQL; 2. Windows only. Based on the statement: "When I was installing SQL I didn't make a SQL server authenticantion, I selected the Windows Authentication option" it seems like you have set up the SQL Server to use windows-only authentication.

Comment: yes I did "use windows-only authenticaiton"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message is from SQL Server so you are clearly connected, the error most likely means either the user id + pwd doesn't match or you have never explicitly granted that user id access to the server and/or the DB you are connecting to.

Comment: how would I grant them the access to the DB

Comment: use mgmt studio, you need to grant them to the server AND the DB.